# Receiving error when Uploading File using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am currently attempting to automate the upload of a file to a specific site. I am able to successfully login to the site and navigate to the import page; however, when I attempt to import the file, I receive an error. My guess is that it is because I am simply a user and am not granted permissions to write to the server. However, if I perform the import  manually, then it is successful. Normally there would be four stages to the import. However, after the first step you can see that an error occurred. My code is listed below along with the error I am receiving:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    login();
}

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void login() throws Exception {   

            // Open the webclient using Internet Explorer (Chrome does not work).
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER);
            // Get the first page
            final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://telephone.qqest.com/phone/Login/Login.asp");
            // Get the form that we are dealing with.
            final HtmlForm loginForm = page.getFormByName("frmLogin");
            final HtmlTextInput userName = loginForm.getInputByName("Login");
            final com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput passWord = (com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput) 
                    loginForm.getInputByName("Password");
            final HtmlTextInput companyID = loginForm.getInputByName("Ident");

            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false); 
            webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
            webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
            //final HtmlInput login = loginForm.getInputByName("Login");

            // Change the values of the text fields.
            userName.setValueAttribute("xxxx");
            passWord.setValueAttribute("xxxxx");
            companyID.setValueAttribute("xxxxx");

            //create a submit button - it doesn't work with 'input'
            DomElement loginBtn = page.createElement("button");
            loginBtn.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            // append the button to the form
            loginForm.appendChild(loginBtn);
            // submit the form
            loginBtn.click();

            //navigate to page for import.
            HtmlPage page3 = webClient.getPage("http://telephone.qqest.com/phone/Imports/Employee/Module.asp");
            //populate the textfield with the specified file.
            final HtmlForm importForm =  page3.getFormByName("ImportForm");
            final HtmlFileInput inputFile = importForm.getInputByName("UploadFile");
            inputFile.setValueAttribute("C:\\Users\\thisFile.xls");
            inputFile.click();
            final HtmlSubmitInput importBtn = (HtmlSubmitInput)importForm.getInputByValue("Import");

            try {
                importBtn.fireEvent(Event.TYPE_INPUT);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }

            HtmlPage page4 = webClient.getPage("http://telephone.qqest.com/phone/Imports/Employee/ImportFile.asp?FileType=application/vnd.ms-excel&FilePath=c%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5Cphone%5CDownloads%5CImports%5C&FileName=thisFile.xls.asp");

            System.out.println("Import Page: " + page4.asText());

    }
```

The error I am receiving:

Stage 1 of 4: Upload File - Completed
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'
 Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.
 /phone/Imports/Employee/ImportFile.asp, line 155

Comment: I think there is no need to click the inputFile. Instead of fireEvent click the importBtn. But without having access to the real page i can only guess what is going wrong.

Comment: The issue was I hadn't declared the importBtn as an HtmlPage so it was not loading the new page after the importBtn was submitted. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a solution and wanted to post it for those who might find it useful in the future. The problem was that I was simply trying to redirect to the import page by using the URL. Prior I had tried to submit the forms with an `importBtn.click()` statement; however, I needed to declare this statement as its own HtmlPage variable.

```
            final HtmlSubmitInput importBtn = (HtmlSubmitInput)importForm.getInputByValue("Import");
            HtmlPage page4 = importBtn.click();

            //  loops until the page changes.
            while(page4 == page3) {
                // The page hasn't changed.
                Thread.sleep(500);

            }
            System.out.println("Import Page: " + page4.asText());
```